# numeric differentiation of electric potential with python

Tags: python, gradient

i used following code to obtain electric field of quadrupole potential.

```
for n in range (nx-1):
  for m in range (ny-1):
   for k in range (nz-1):
     Ex[n,m,k] =-( (T[n+1,m,k]-T[n,m,k]) )/((x[n+1]-x[n]));
     Ey[n,m,k] =-( (T[n,m+1,k]-T[n,m,k]) )/((y[m+1]-y[m]));
     Ez[n,m,k] =-( (T[n,m,k+1]-T[n,m,k]) )/((z[k+1]-z[k]));
     return Ex,Ey,Ez, T
```

[image: quad_potential and electric field]
here T is potential in 3D obtained by solving Laplace equation numerically, as you can see from figure red electrode (positive) has wrong electric field vector direction (right upper side and right down side of top electrode ) same mistake also in the other electrodes. i.e. negative electrode has outgoing electric field vector which must be opposite direction.

I also used central difference method but i get same figure. Could you please tell me what is wrong with my differentiation?

Comment: To find a solution you have to include your actual code, including the plot.  It is just as likely that your bug is in the plot as it is in the gradient.  Specifically, this smells like the kind of bug where you are unclear as to which points are which positions.  In creating the actual code, you could simplify by finding the potential directly rather than solving the Laplace equation.

Comment: actual code is very long to upload here. I used matplotlib "quiver" to get this figure

Comment: Well, if you're unwilling to share your code, it's unlikely anyone will be able to find your bug.  Ideally, you would give a simplified example that demonstrates the problem.  I don't see anything wrong with the gradient, so probably the bug is elsewhere.  My best guess from your figure (if the contour lines are contours of potential, which you don't say) is that you've transposed the arguments to quiver.  But again, we can't say for certain without seeing code.

Comment: Dear David, of course i am willing to share code as i told it is very long to upload here, may i send as an email to you? .

Comment: You could post it to github, or again, you could simplify it.  e.g. try finding the gradient of an analytic function, and just plot that.

Comment: It's still not runnable as you didn't post PhysicalConstants.py, but I have one suggestion:  in your quivers and contours, use X and Y rather than x and y.  It seems likely that you and matplotlib are disagreeing on which direction is which.  Also, it looks like you have z and x swapped in your xz plot.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the way in which matplotlib interprets the directions, which itself originates in the way *matrices* are conventionally indexed, which is the reverse of what many people (such as myself) would think.  Specifically, the first index is the *vertical* index, while the second index is the *horizontal* index.  This would have been made clear if you had used a non-square array, which would have revealed that your `x` and `y` were backwards.  The following example illustrates how your gradient (only very slightly modified) gives the correct result.  The first figure shows what you were actually plotting, which had the x and y components of the gradients swapped.  The figure (which you can get by running this) demonstrates that the gradient is not orthogonal to the contour lines (as it must be) and sometimes goes in the wrong direction.

The second and third figures both show a correct way to plot the gradient using the nice approach in which we have 2D arrays for the coordinates as well as the thing we're plotting (whether `quiver` or `contour`).  I follow your code in using `meshgrid` to generate my `X` and `Y`, but needed to swap the arguments to `meshgrid` to get the dimensions right.  A cleaner approach would be to use the same coding style to generate the coordinates as the thing plotted, in this case a while loop with explicit indices would have been optimal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-3,3,0.2)
y = np.arange(-5,5,0.2)
z = np.arange(-5,5,0.2)

def grad(f):
    gx = np.zeros_like(f)
    gy = np.zeros_like(f)
    gz = np.zeros_like(f)
    for n in range(1,len(x)-1):
        for m in range(1,len(y)-1):
            for k in range(1,len(z)-1):
                gx[n,m,k] = (T[n+1,m,k]-T[n-1,m,k])/(x[n+1]-x[n-1]);
                gy[n,m,k] = (T[n,m+1,k]-T[n,m-1,k])/(y[m+1]-y[m-1]);
                gz[n,m,k] = (T[n,m,k+1]-T[n,m,k-1])/(z[k+1]-z[k-1]);
    return gx, gy, gz

T = np.zeros((len(x), len(y), len(z)))
for n in range(len(x)):
    for m in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            T[n,m,k] = np.sin((x[n] - y[m])/3.0) + 0.3*np.cos(y[m]) + z[k]**2

gx,gy,gz = grad(T)

Y, X= np.meshgrid(y,x)

plt.figure('WRONG with x and y')
plt.contour(y, x, T[:,:,round(len(z)/2)], 64)
plt.colorbar()
plt.quiver(y, x, 10*gx[:,:,round(len(z)/2)], 10*gy[:,:,round(len(z)/2)])
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')


plt.figure('with X and Y')
plt.contour(X, Y, T[:,:,round(len(z)/2)], 64)
plt.colorbar()
plt.quiver(X, Y, 10*gx[:,:,round(len(z)/2)], 10*gy[:,:,round(len(z)/2)])
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')

plt.figure('with Y and X')
plt.contour(Y, X, T[:,:,round(len(z)/2)], 64)
plt.colorbar()
plt.quiver(Y, X, 10*gy[:,:,round(len(z)/2)], 10*gx[:,:,round(len(z)/2)])
plt.xlabel("Y")
plt.ylabel("X")
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

Finally, I'll point out again, the cleanest way to reveal this bug would have been to run your program with `nx != ny`.  The code would have failed with an error message indicating that array dimensions didn't match, which would have led you to swapping things around (hopefully) in the right way.

Comment: dear David, many thanks for your answer. I also post PhysicsConstant.py to githup.

Comment: Hi David, i have solved electric vector direction. The problem was exactly what you said above. When i interpolate these electric field what coordinate should i use X (from meshgrid) or x (from real coordinate) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking when you ask about interpolation.  X and x contain the same information.  X is just a 2D array that matches the dimensions of your 2D slice.  Either could work for you, depending on how you want to do the interpolation.